# table display block not working on media query

Tags: html, css

I have a table and here is my CSS:

```
table {
 display: block;
 height: 500px;
 overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

when i add this inline it is ok but on external not working (on media query max width 767px)

Edit | my media query

```
@media(max-width:767px) {
 table {
  display: block;
  height: 500px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
}
```

Comment: can you include the media query that you're having problem with?

Comment: here is edited question

Comment: is your media query at the bottom of the css styles?

Comment: it is on responsive.css with other media queries

Comment: your links on your `head` to should be, `main css` and under it is the `responsive css`

Comment: it is like you say

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/141598/discussion-between-gvm-and-volkan).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try putting your table into a `div` wrapper. Like so:

```
<div class='table-container'>
  <table></table>
</div>
```

Then in your CSS simply set

```
.table-container > table {
  height:100%;
  width: 100%;
}

.table-container {
  height: 500px;
}
```

See this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/r5dqmoyr/)